# Apache 403 on certain folders

Tags: apache, web, centos

I'm running dev server on Centos 6.4 with Apache 2.2. I just moved a site from the production to dev to perform upgrades. I modified file owner to apache:apache (httpd user) and set all directories to 755 and files to 644. I have few other sites in the DocumentRoot folder with similar settings and they run fine (using same CMS, PHP, MySQL versions etc).

I have no virtual hosts defined and Allow all on everything. httpd.conf is default.

I'm not able to make site working from the folder I just moved from the production. I'm getting 403 every time.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in

https://serverfault.com/questions/272947/apache-on-centos-5-6-gives-me-permissions-denied-error/272956#272956

> Usually that comes from Selinux not giving access to the folder. do
>
> ls -alZ /var/www
>
> and if the html folder doesn't have the context system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t, fix it with chcon
>
> chcon -v -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html
>
> http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux